# salesforce rest api

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-service-cloud

I am new to salesforce. I need to know how to design a WSDL for salesforce REST API inorder to connect salesforce service?

I have a doubt, is it possible to do a GET request(sales force has REST access) on sales force resources and create xsd based on the response xml received for each request?

But I cant able to find particular schema available for salesforce.
or

Is there any other way to design a WSDL for REST API?

Thank you for your answer in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the REST API, you don't need to use the WSDL. You can explore the API by going to

https://{instance}.salesforce.com/services/data/v24.0

For an interactive explorer, check out apigee's salesforce console:

https://apigee.com/console/salesforce

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Workbench to make REST calls to Salesforce:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a WSDL file for your org by going to Setup->Build->Develop->API and click on 'Generate Enterprise WSDL'. The Enterprise WSDL will contain your full schema in xsd structure.

Regarding a doubt about creating an XSD based on the response, XML received from a GET request. It is not possible, and REST doesn't require WSDL. You will only need endpoints and HTTP methods. The Salesforce REST API documentation provides the schema for each resource in JSON format. You can use this JSON schema to generate an XSD if needed.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm